# EditText gets activated automatically

Tags: android, focus, android-edittext

If I press any alphabet/number when application gets launched, `EditText` gets activated automatically and starts searching for the corresponding string.

For eg., On app launch, if user presses alphabet 'A' by mistake, `EditText` fetched that and shows all results starting from 'A'.

Actually it should be activated and should display corresponding result **if and only if** a user clicks on `EditText`, and **not otherwise**.

I tried this in `main.xml`

```
    android:focusable="false"
    android:clickable="true"
```

and in `activity class`

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);      
            lsym = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lsym);
        edsearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edsearch);

            dbM = new DbManager(this);
            symbolarr = dbM.getSymbol();
            edsearch.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                     edsearch.setFocusable(true);
                    edsearch.requestFocus();
                }
            });

            edsearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                        int before, int count) {

                    //FILTERING LIST
                }
            });
}
```

, but it takes the focus away from `EditText` permanently and doesn't get focus again even if it is clicked.

What am I doing wrong?

**ANY HELP WILL BE LIFE-SAVER !!!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use below attributes for parent layout

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Comment: yeah, 3 of them. But how does that make any difference?

Comment: You can move focus to one of TextView when activity launch. So it will easily solve your problem.

Comment: You can apply requestFocus() to any of your textview. This will not give focus to EditText on activity launch which you don't want.

Comment: I tried `tv1.requestFocus();` in `onCreate()` and `editText.requestFocus();` on `editText click`... But it doesn't work. You suggested the same na?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6262/discussion-between-nisha-113a5-and-gama)

Comment: Your following suggestion on chat worked.

1. Make parent layout Focusable True. In parent layout apply `android:focusable="true"` and `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"`.
2. In on create method, apply `txtView.requestFocus();` to `TextView`
3. In on create method, apply `editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);` to `EditText`

Answer (score 0):

Either your main.xml file contains

```
<requestFocus/>
```

tag or it is enabled in programming code
you can use

> requestFocus() method

Comment: I tried `editText.setFocusable(true);  
editText.requestFocus();` in my `onClick()` to `editText` , but no luck...

Comment: Ok then I haven't got any answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in one of my applications when I first stated developing. Now I don't understand the nature of your problem, but this worked for me.

*It is a fix, I might add and merely prevents the soft-keyboard from coming up the moment an activity is launched. This will prevent the accidental key-inputs after the activity has launched.*

Add this to the activity's java code in question.

```
private void hideKeyboard() {
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

    }
```

Comment: @GAMA: Can you also post the onCreate method of your activity? And I hope my assumption that you are talking about the soft-keyboard is correct.